# Websraping dynamicly generated web content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to websrape text from a web page using Python and beutifulsoup library. The text that I am trying to get is contained in a  tag that is visible in the browser's inspector (developer tools) as

`<h2 data-v-a4f7566c="" class="name">Racio lky sýrové</h2>`

The wabpage: [https://www.kosik.cz/c1026-pekarna-a-cukrarna](https://stackoverflow.com)

This is the reason why

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
 def get_product_names(soup):
    product_names = []
    for h2 in soup.find_all("h2"):
        product_names.append(h2.text)
    return product_names
   product_names = get_product_names(soup)
```

returns "none".

However, when I take a look at the page source, I can see no  tag there.

This bring me to the conclusion that the  tag is being generated by javascript.

**Question**: Is there a way how one can websrap dynamicly generated contant using beutifulsoup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce you're problem, worked for me with :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html5lib
import json
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver

def get_product_names(soup):
   product_names = []
   for h2 in soup.find_all("h2"): # or find_all("h2", {"class":"name"})
      product_names.append(h2.text)
   return product_names 

URL = "https://www.kosik.cz/c1026-pekarna-a-cukrarna" 
service = Service()
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service,options=options)
driver.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
product_names = get_product_names(soup)
```

I got the following list in product_names:

['Racio lky sýrové',
'Racio Cornies Kukuřičné chlebíčky se lněným semínkem',
'Biopekárna Zemanka BIO Dýňové krekry se špaldou a česnekem',
'Bauli Croisaant Bauli vanilkový',
'PAC Hořovice Loupák sypaný (2ks) ',
'Hradecká pekárna Low carb Proteinové pečivo, 2x65g',
'Racio Knäckebrot žitný s vysokým obsahem vlákniny',
'Nový Věk Kukuřičné lupínky - Mořská sůl',
'Nový Věk Rýžové chlebíčky kakaové',
'Racio Free Style Rýžové chlebíčky s příchutí rajče a bazalka',
'Merhautovo pekařství Veka krájená balená',
'Nutrifree Bezlepkový Domácí krájený chléb (4x75g)',
'Bauli Croissant Bauli čokoládový',
'Biopekárna Zemanka BIO Medové perníčky',
'Biopekárna Zemanka BIO Bezlepkové pohankové perníčky s medem',
'Nutrifree Bezlepkové Hamburger housky 180g']

Comment: What I was missing was the use of the selenium. The part of the code implementing selenium that you proposed has resolved the issue. Many thanks

Comment: how many unused `import`s do you have?

Answer (score 0):

In browser DevTools go to `Network` tab and there search for string you want "Racio lky sýrové". If it is loaded dynamically, it will be there as separate request. Then you can do the same request in your code.

Comment: this answer has correctness holes, but that isn't a reason to delete it if it genuinely attempts to answer the question.